# How to run AlertDialog or DialogFragment quickly?

Tags: java, android

I have a `Fragment` that does the following:

```
showProgressBar();

controller.calc();

setTextResult();

hiddenProgressBar();
```

My `showProgressBar`:

```
ProgressBar loadingCalc = new ProgressBar(requireContext(), null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyle);
loadingCalc.setId(View.generateViewId());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
loadingCalc.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext(), R.style.Dialog)
        .setView(loadingCalc)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .create();

alertDialog.show();
```

My `hiddenProgressBar`:

```
if (alertDialog != null) {
  alertDialog.dismiss();
}
```

First the Fragment executes the `showProgressBar`, leaving the AlertDialog visible. Then it calculates and in the end executes the `hiddenProgressBar`. Visually it doesn't. When I run the application it first performs the calculation and at the end it shows the `AlertDialog`and quickly withdraws it.

What the code is doing:
Calculate > showing the `AlertDialog`> hiding the `AlertDialog`

What should happen:
Show `AlertDialog` > Calculate > Hide `AlertDialog`

Observation: I've already tried using `DialogFragment` but it has the same behavior as `AlertDialog`. I just want a `Dialog` with a `ProgressBar` while Android does a calculation that can take a while.

How can I solve this?

Comment: How long does it take to do the calculation? You can actually use determinate progress bar to update user on the progress. Or use a Handler to dismiss after few sec or mill sec.

Comment: The calculation will take time depending on the number the user provides @Basu

Comment: You need to do the calculation off the main thread